# I want to make the method I bypassed with frida tool permanent

Tags: reverse-engineering, reverse, frida, bypass

I want the application that I bypass using frida to be permanent and to run in this code without running frida

Example Command:

```
frida -U -f com.xxxxxxx.package -l root.js
```

I wanted to use apk patcher tool but it doesn't work

Comment: I mean;

I want to enter javascript code into apk

Answer (score 2):

In every Frida release you will find libraries called ["Frida Gadget"](https://frida.re/docs/gadget/) which is effectively Frida not as executable but as a library which can be embedded into an app. Together with the frida gadget library (e.g. `frida-gadget-16.1.4-android-arm64.so`) you can embed a configuration file and a Frida JavaScript file that will be executed on the app the library is running in.

You can rename the frida gadget library e.g. to `libfrida-gadget.so` and place it in the app directory `/lib/arm64-v8a/` within the APK file.

Embedding Frida gadget library into an app allows to modify the app at run-time even on un-rooted devices.

For integrating frida gadget library you have to make minor modifications to the smali code of the app: at some point you have to load the frida gadget library (preferably early in the app start process).
To modify the APK my recommendation is to use `apktool` with the option to not decompile resources as resources often causes problems: `apktool d --no-res apkfile.apk`.

The code to be added

```
# adapt the const-string to the name of the frida gadget library 
# "frida-gadget" -> file name "libfrida-gadget.so"
const-string v0, "frida-gadget"
invoke-static {v0}, Ljava/lang/System;->loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

The common points for adding this code is in the `clinit` method of the main activity (see `AndroidManifest.xml`)  or the application class (the class that extends `android.app.Application`). If there is no `clinit`method in those classes you can add it:

```
.method static constructor <clinit>()V
    .registers 1
    const-string v0, "frida-gadget"
    invoke-static {v0}, Ljava/lang/System;->loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    return-void
.end method
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try and let you know, I hope it works. ♥